# nuxt.js !process.server never gets in the if statement

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

hello guys i have following problem:

I have an nuxt.js page that is called "dashboard" and i made an middleware for it it looks like this:

```
export default {
   components: {
      overview
   },
   middleware: "authentication"
};
```

and in my authentication.js file:

```
  import axios from "axios";
  export default async function({ store, redirect }) {
  if (!store.state.authentication.authenticated) {
    if (!process.server) {
      console.log("i am in statement");
      if (!window.localStorage.getItem("realtime_jwt_token")) {
        return redirect("/");
      } else {
        const checkJwt = await axios.post("/api/checkToken", {
          token: window.localStorage.getItem("realtime_jwt_token")
        });
        if (checkJwt.data) {
          return null;
        }
        window.localStorage.removeItem("realtime_jwt_token");
        return redirect("/");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `console.log("i am in statement")` never displays in my browser neither on the server console and i am always able to access the dashboard site.
Why doesnt `!process.server` work here?

EDIT:

I found out why.

Middleware runs once on the server side if you put your mode on "universal".
To access the client side you should put your mode to "spa" or u look for another solution

Answer (score -1):

You probably have problem not with process.server but with previous statement "store.state.authentication.authenticated". Did You checked that with another console.log above?

Comment: This should be a comment on his question and not a Answer

Comment: Heard about new users limitations?